# ReactJS + Angular + Babel

Tags: angularjs, react

Bom dia
Estou precisando utilizar o ReactJS em um projeto que já utilizo o AngularJS. Consegui fazer a integração, porém sem utilizar o Babel, ou seja, somente consegui fazer o Angular e o ReactJS se comunicarem através do React puro. Alguém saberia me dizer como posso fazer essa integração e utilizar o Babel???

Comment: Já deu uma olhada nessa lib? https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact

Comment: Sim, mas o pessoal da equipe não quer usar. :(

Comment: Entendi, na minha opinião React e Angular são pra finalidades diferentes, não vejo muito sentido em utilizar os dois juntos.

Comment: E pior é que essa biblioteca não renderiza o Babel

Answer (score 1):

Por que não incluir o script do Babel assim (depois de incluir react e react-dom):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
```

E definir os scripts que usam React com o atributo `text/babel`:

`<script type="text/babel" src="seu_react.js"></script>`